# Eclipse - run a task on Eclipse shutdown / exit

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

is it possible to run a task/script automatically when eclipse is closing?

I can't find a proper option in the preferences neither a plugin which can help solving this issue.

I use the perforce Plugin for Eclipse and i want to run a [shelf](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Shelving.html) task automatically before eclipse closes.

Many thanks
Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a framework adaptor hook.  This allows you to plug into the OSGi runtime at a slightly lower level than eclipse plugins do.  Essentially, a framework adaptor hook is a plugin fragment that implements the `org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.hooks.AdaptorHook` interface.  This interface has a `frameworkStop` and `frameworkStopping` method that you can implement and probably runs at the time that you need it to.

Here is some good information on adaptor hooksL http://wiki.eclipse.org/Adaptor_Hooks

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks that sounds like a good plan. Looks like i can achieve my plan  with the Adaptor hook.

Comment: Andrew do you have an example for the Adapter Hook implementation. I tried to integrate (like described in your link) it in a small hello world plugin but it seems that it isn't loaded correctly.

Comment: I have used it before in groovy-eclipse. Have a look at this:https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/tree/master/base/org.codehaus.groovy.frameworkadapter

Comment: That helped pretty much, thank you. Seems when using the framework adapter hook i have problems when the plugin require other (third party) plugins.

Comment: THat's correct.  The fragment has the same classpath as the host bundle.

Comment: Andrew if you don't mind another question :-) I added an external lib (jar file) in my frameworks adapter hook plugin. I included it over the Manifest configuration screen --> runtime --> classpath. It is referenced in the Manifest.mf : Bundle-ClassPath: lib/my_external.jar (and of course in the build.properties) which seems correct to me. But when i start my elcipse instance i get an java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError which points to an Class in the my_external.jar. The lib/my_external.jar lives in the plugin.jar. Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Hm ok seems that the lib isn't loded when "frameworkStart" is called. That's a pity

Comment: This is getting towards the edge of my understanding.  You could try making sure that your fragment is exploded (ie- unzipped) when it is installed.

Comment: Ok how do i check if it is explodeD? "frameworkStart" is called directly after "initialize" seems that the thrid party jar isn't loaded in the classpath at this time.

Comment: Found a solution for my problem: in the "frameworkStart" method of my hook i register a framworkListener (context.addFrameworkListener). With that listener i can react on the Framework Started event. Which is sufficent for my case. Anyway Many thanks Andrew for your help!! Have a good day